# Restful API codeigniter - JAVA issue

Tags: java, api, codeigniter

We built our API using [Phil Sturgeons cool Restful API framework for codeigniter](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/06/REST-implementation-for-CodeIgniter), which is production ready and is used as part of our mobile apps implementation.

We have an issue when using the API in Java

```
httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url, Connector.READ, true);
// Set content type by given parameter......
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", contentType);
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/FCLDC-1.0");
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("TK-API-KEY", UrlFactory.TK_API_KEY);

// httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Model",
// StyleUtil.getDeviceModel());
if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == 302)
{
  String redirectUrl =  httpConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
  httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(redirectUrl, Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
}

if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
{
  io = httpConnection.openInputStream();

  int ch;
  while ((ch = io.read()) != -1)
  {
    bo.write(ch);
  }

}
```

`httpConnection.getResponseCode()` is unable to get the status code and returns a malformed exception. Our API server is NGINX.

Comment: Could you post what it returns?

Comment: If [CI](http://codeigniter.com) is not necessary you could give a chance to [jabsorb](http://code.google.com/p/jabsorb/).

Comment: simply try a URL first, from a console java app and proceed from there.

Comment: try using a client like Advanced REST Client (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) to see what the server returns. if you can post the response header it will be a lot helpful

Comment: Try poster, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/poster/ or SOAP UI http://www.soapui.org/ to test your REST request/response. You could even use CURL from the command like if you are on a *NIX machine. Doing this will validate the information you are requesting is available and you can troubleshoot more from there.

Comment: The second code block in mkyongs article is a Java client to do what @BinaryNights suggested: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/

Answer (score 1):

MalformedException is thrown in case header fields are not set properly. Please check with different headers and also with different user agents. Trying using
httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);